# How can I create enum dynamically in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a two lender types that have almost the same enum values. But I have to exclude some enum value on a specific lender type. So I would like to ask if I can create or manipulate enum values in angular?

So I have an existing declared enum.

```
enum EnumList {
    enum1 = 1,
    enum2 = 2,
    enum3 = 3,
    enum4 = 4,
    enum5 = 5
}
```

So if I am on LenderType = A, I would like to exclude enum4 on my EnumList and then for LenderType = B, Id like to display all.

If ever, I would like to place it on a single method for getting my enumList that automatically separated by LenderType.

Comment: Why not just have two separate enums?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yeah that's the idea. But I'm looking if there is any way to manipulate enums because I dont want to duplicate the enumlist.

Comment: Maybe a utility type? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu
```type EnumList = Exclude<EnumList, EnumList.Enum4>``` ?

Comment: @nullptr.t cool. I will check this.